# List new item page for mobile - Different from the set default page

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile-view

I created a custom new item page for my SharePoint online and set it as the default new item page.
However when I try to add a new item from my mobile browser, it takes me to /_layouts/15/mobile/newforma.aspx

How can I force mobile clients to use my custom page for new item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you are aware of the **Mobile Browser View** feature of SharePoint.

Just navigate

- `Site Settings -> Manage Site Features`
- Find `Mobile Browser View`
- Deactivate

This will help you.